# Store the Strings by splitting on a comma in an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split

I have a `config.property` file in which I have below property-

```
Table1.columns: ACCOUNT, ADVERTISING, INFO, BEHAVIOR, CHURN, SEGMENTATION,
```

I am trying to read the above property file and then store those `columns` by splitting on a `comma` in an `ArrayList`

So I am using the below way. Is there any better way of doing the same thing? Here `arg` is `Table1`

```
ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();

Collections.addAll(columns, prop.getProperty(arg + ".columns").split(","));
```

Comment: are you loading thee Property file correctly ?

Comment: Yes, I am loading it fine. I removed those snippet code from here.

Comment: ok, then store the contents from the propfile in a string variable and then do the split.i'd also check if the String variable contains what you except by debuggin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) :

```
List<String> columns = 
     Arrays.asList( prop.getProperty(arg + ".columns").split(",") );
```

Comment: I already tried this approach. I am getting error as `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to ArrayList<String>` As my columns have been declared as `ArrayList<String>` not `List<String>`.

Comment: Well, declare it as a list then.

Comment: Yes, sure, that's why I used the type `List<String>`. If you *really* need an ArrayList, just use something like `columns = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList(...) )`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
prop.getProperty(arg + ".columns").split("\\s*,\\s*")
```